# What does the -f mean between the 2 filenames for a cronjob entry?

Tags: shell-script, cron

I'm just looking through a *cronjob* entry, and I'm not too sure on what the 2 filenames and the *-f* mean. I'm trying to VIM the shell script to see what it does. Any ideas please?

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/ccproxy
```

Comment: The manpages are your friend and would have given you a quicker answer:  [logrotate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html)

Answer (score 3):

That would be an invocation of `/usr/sbin/logrotate` with its command line flag `-f` (same as `--force`) to force a rotation of the logs according to the configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d/ccproxy`.

Log rotation usually happens on regular intervals, maybe by an hourly cron job, and `logrotate` will rotate the log files that have either grown too big or too old (according to the rotation configuration). With `-f`, one forces rotation regardless of the age and size of the log files.

This cron job is set up to trigger a forced rotation of the logs according to the configuration in a particular configuration file at regular intervals.